# Dynamic Type Static UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, dynamic-type-feature

I have a static `UITableView` with a `UITableViewCell` that contains a label. I have it set up to look nice right now, but when a user has their Dynamic Type turned to a larger setting, the label is cut off.

The `UILabel` has static ~15px constraints set up on all four edges of the `UITableViewCell's` content view.

How can I make the `UITableViewCell's` height change dynamically as the Dynamic Type adjusts the size of the `UILabel's` body formatted text.

Comment: use tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification and when you get notified change your heightforRowAtIndexPath accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this question many years ago but, as you didn't share any solution here, I guess you didn't find one.

Standard table view cells content is automatically adjusted thanks to the [cell-sizing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/245/?time=1058) feature.
[image]

Constraints must be adapted in case of custom cells in order to obtain the desired rendering and let the cell-sizing work. 
[image]

If your table view cells don't size to fit content, try and use the properties `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` associated to `estimatedRowHeight`.

Finally, check out this [WWDC video detailed summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html#wwdc-2017-building-apps-with-dynamic-type) dealing with the best way to build apps with Dynamic Type if the explanations above aren't enough.